# why does hbase need nodemanager when it uses coprocessors

Tags: hbase, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Node Manager is used to start, execute and monitor containers on YARN(containers are assigned to execute map-red jobs).
Co-processor on the other hand is a framework which does distributed computation directly within the HBase server processes.
I have tables in HBase which I query using phoenix. My doubt is when I have coprocessor which is doing the computation and fetching the result from HBase, then why do I need Node Manager at all.
The reason I ask this question is currently on my YARN UI, I see the three nodes of my cluster, which has 8GB&8core assigned to it. But none of it is getting used while I fire query at HBase. The no of container created is 0 as well.
Can someone please help me understand this concept or refer any link. Any help would be highly appreciated.